# Laravel mix is compiling only app files others are just recopied

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, laravel-5.7

As title says when I run `npm run dev or run watch` it compiles just app.js and app.scss to public as it should but for additional files it just recopy content.

Using Laravel 5.7 and I added two additional files to resources (`user.js` & `user.scss`)

Also I added two more lines into webpack.mix:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/user.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/sass/user.scss', 'public/css');
```

User files are just recopied like those in resource folder..

This works fine in laravel 5.6 and same files are used..

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get only one file in `public` you need to add `require('./user');` at the end of your `app.js`.

Same for scss files, add `@import 'user';` into `app.scss`, but rename `user.scss` to `_user.scss`.

For separate files in my project on `laravel 5.7`

```
// App
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

// Admin
mix.js('resources/js/admin.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: I never said i want that... I need two files

Comment: do want them to be "compiled" when you are in dev ?